# How to cumsum a column value baed on event change in other column using python?

Tags: python-3.x, event-handling, cumsum

I have a problem in which I need cumsum of column max_count for every event change like below:

Input:

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxhXv.png)

Desired Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0L5Z.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of including images, can you put the input and desired output as text in your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.